# Custom post with custom URL

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post, and I would like the URL to be:

```
example.com/directory/profile/slug/
```

With that in mind, this is a snap shot of how I have set it up:

```
$args = array(
  ...
  'rewrite'       => array( 'slug' => 'directory/profile' ),
  'supports'      => array( 'title', 'thumbnail' ),
);
```

I have created a corresponding file:

```
single-profile.php
```

If I remove the `directory/` from the rewrite parameter, the new post shows up at this URL:

```
example.com/profile/slug/
```

I have looked at adding *rewrite* rules but either thats not the right approach or I am not doing that correctly.

Example:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
  '^directory/profile/([^/]+)/?$',
  'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&post_type=profile',
  'top'
);
```

What extra steps do I need to get this to work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it is: go to `settings > permalinks`, select **Custom** and set the value to `/%postname%/`.

No need for the rewrite rules.
Keep the post type slug as `directory/profile`.

Note that this will also change the default posts URLs to `/postname`. If you want to apply this change only for the post type, you can use [this plugin](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/), making the change above only for this post type.

Or do it on the code using the [post_type_link hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/), also works.

Comment: Yes I only need to do it for this one post type, not all post types. Adding a plugin to solve for this is not a viable option.